# estimated roots with multiplicity forming a pattern around the true location

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, exponential-function, roots

I am estimating the roots of a complex polynomial, and it is found that the estimates form a pattern around the true location of the eigenvalue, as shown in the attachment. The number of estimates around the true location is the multiplicity of the root. Is there any explanation for this behaviour?  Also, the distance between the true and estimated location increases, with increasing multiplicity.

[image: Location of estimated roots around the true location]

Comment: This is a bit vague. Perhaps you can explain *how* you estimate roots, and what exactly is show in the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very interesting theorem in complex analysis that goes like follows

**Theorem:** Suppose $f$ is analytic on $B(a,R)$ and let $f(a) = \alpha$. If $g(z) = f(z) - \alpha$ has a zero of multiplicity $m$ at $z = a$, then $\exists \epsilon, \delta > 0$ such that for $0<|\zeta - \alpha|<\delta$ the equation $f(z) = \zeta$ has exactly $m$ simple roots in $B(a,\epsilon)$

So, what you are witnessing is just this theorem in action.

**Explanation:** Since $f$ is a polynomial it is analytic (continuous with continuous derivative). Say $a \in \mathbb{C}$ is such that $f(a) = \alpha = 0$, and say $a$ has multiplicity $m$ as in the theorem (that is to say, $g(z) = f(z)$ in the theorem), then if you pick some $\zeta$ an estimate of the root, close enough to $0$ (here I am assuming you are estimating by looking at the value of $f$ in contours around $a$ and letting the contours zero in on $a$ that way), then $f(z) = \zeta$ will have $m$ simple roots in the disk around $a$, which is exactly what you are observing.

Comment: Thank you Arun.  Can I get the reference to this theorem for further study?

Comment: Theorem 7.4 in https://math.unice.fr/~nivoche/pdf/Conway1.pdf